# "invalid transaction termination" in Postgres when trying to update a value using a function

Tags: postgresql, transaction, functions, plpgsql

I'm new to postgres. I defined a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_count() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql 
  AS $$
   BEGIN 
     UPDATE posts SET count=count+1 WHERE pid=NEW.pid;
   COMMIT;
   END;
  $$;
```

This gives me error `invalid transaction termination`

Comment: On which table is that trigger defined? Are there any more details in the Postgres logfile?

Comment: There is another table that keeps track of user's like. and the trigger is bound to `INSERT` to that table

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to have that `commit` inside a trigger function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not commit in a trigger, and you forgot the return statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_count() 
  RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql 
  AS $$
    BEGIN 
      UPDATE posts SET count=count+1 WHERE pid=NEW.pid;
      return null;
    END;
  $$;
```

In case of a BEFORE trigger, "return NEW" should be used!

Comment: So even without a `COMMIT` will it be treated as a transaction?

Comment: @zk_regen: anything the trigger does is part of the transaction that cause the trigger to fire

Comment: Are you sure that `RETURN NULL` is correct, rather than `RETURN NEW`? It might cancel the operation.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, it might, if this function was called by a before trigger.